# Convert double to BigInteger

Tags: java, floating-point, biginteger, bigint

How do you convert a double to a BigInteger, as accurately as possible? BigInteger doesn't have a valueOf(double) method. It does have a valueOf(long) method, but converting via long, would destroy any value outside the 2^64 range, and in particular I'm trying to get large numbers like 1e100 to convert to their corresponding integer values  to the sixteen or so significant figures allowed by floating point precision.

Comment: BigInteger will destroy that info to...

Comment: i hope you know that `Double.MAX_VALUE` is somewhere around 1.7*10^308...

Comment: @MartinFrank: No problem for a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the double into a BigDecimal and then into a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger k = BigDecimal.valueOf(doublevalue).toBigInteger();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-) and then call [`toBigIntegerExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigIntegerExact--) on that. Like,

```
BigInteger bi = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.PI).toBigIntegerExact();
```

Comment: That would throw an error, because is *π* not exactly 3 anyway. If you want to avoid errors, use `toBigInteger()`.